# Python Multiprocessing: is locking appropriate for (large) disk writes?

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing

I have multiprocessing code wherein each process does a disk write (pickling data), and the resulting pickle files can be upwards of 50 MB (and sometimes even more than 1 GB depending on what I'm doing). Also, different processes are not writing to the same file, each process writes a separate file (or set of files).

Would it be a good idea to implement a lock around disk writes so that only one process is writing to the disk at a time? Or would it be best to just let the operating system sort it out even if that means 4 processes may be trying to write 1 GB to the disk at the same time?

Comment: What do you hope to gain by limiting your code to one writing process at a time?

Comment: That's what I'm not entirely sure of, but my thinking is this: The disk write capacity (as shown in Windows Task Manager) often gets maxed out or nearly maxed out by just one process writing to the disk. If two or more are trying to write at the same time, it definitely gets maxed out. I fear that the bottleneck created there would slow down my code more than if each process just waited for the others before trying to write. But I don't know... maybe the operating system would handle it smoothly and result in faster completion with multiple processes writing at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the processes aren't fighting over the same file; let the OS sort it out. That's its job.

Unless your processes try and dump their data in one big write, the OS is in a better position to schedule disk writes.
If you do use one big write, you mighy try and partition it in smaller chunks. That might give the OS a better chance of handling them.

Of course you will hit a limit somewhere. Your program might be the CPU-bound, memory-bound or disk-bound. It might hit different limits depending on the input or load.
But unless you've got *evidence* that you're *constantly* disk-bound *and* you've got a good idea how to solve that, I'd say don't bother. Because the days that a `write` system call actuall meant that the data was directly sent to disk are long gone.

Most operating systems these days use unallocated RAM as a disk cache. And HDD's have built-in caches as well. Unless you disable both of these (which will give you a *huge* performance hit) there is *precious little connection* between your program completing a `write` and and the data actually hitting the plates or flash.

You might consider using `memmap` (if your OS supports it), and let the OS's virtual memory do the work for you. See e.g. the [architect notes for the Varnish cache](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ArchitectNotes).